# Issue installing OpenVPN via apt

Tags: debian, apt, openvpn

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1kHJ2qSg)

I wanted to install OpenVPN on my Debian Wheezy server at home, so I could create a tunnel with my phone or tablet from outside my home. We use OpenVPN at work, so I figured it would be easy enough to setup, given my experience.

When I execute (as root) `apt-get install openvpn`, it looks like it installs, then fails. OK, I'll check what `dpkg --audit` has to say about it. It claims that it's not configured properly. Alright, I run `dpkg --configure openvpn`, but I just get an error about the boot order. It claims to conflict with minidlna and denyhosts, two services I run at home. I have minidlna so I can watch my media on my other devices (i.e. my XBox), and denyhosts to block a lot of script kiddies who try to get into my website.

I would prefer to not have to remove those packages, but is there some way I can get OpenVPN to install on this box?

Comment: Please post output of `apt-get install openvpn` and `dpkg --configure openvpn`. How do you know it conflicts with minidlna and denyhosts?

Comment: @FaheemMitha From the Pastebin link above. It was long, so I figured linking to it was best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LSB headers at the top of scripts in /etc/init.d/ define a bit more about the program and what they depend on. It looks like there's no LSB headers in the denyhosts init script. You could try to update (apt-get update) and then reinstall the package (apt-get install --reinstall denyhosts) but changes are you'll get the same (incorrect) script back.

Try to add these generic LSB headers to the denyhosts init.d script (just under the #!/bin/sh line) and see if it helps.

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          denyhosts
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     
# Should-Start:      
# Should-Stop:       
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start or stop denyhosts
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: Added those lines right after the `#!usr/bin/env python` declaration, and now OpenVPN installs! Now I can continue on with setting it up